# why does '\\\[' equals '\\[' ? How does backslash work in string?

Tags: javascript

As the title

```js
console.log('\\\[' === '\\[');
```

returns true.

Can anyone explain in detail what's the difference?

Comment: because `[` doesn't need to be escaped, i.e. `'\[' === '['`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A backslash before *most* characters will only be parsed as an unnecessary escape character - the backslash will be ignored. This is what's happening in the second part of the first string. Before a certain *few* characters though, such as another backslash in `\\`, or `\n`, it will be parsed as a *escape sequence*. `\\` is the escape sequence for a single literal backslash:

```js
console.log('\\');
```

and is only one character.

A backslash before a `[` will resolve to just the `[`, though:

```js
console.log('\[');
```

So:

`'\\\['` - A literal backslash, followed by an (unnecessarily escaped) `[`

`'\\['` - A literal backslash, followed by a plain `[`

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Using_special_characters_in_strings) for a list of escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

In strings, the backslash (`\`) is a special character used to [encode other special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation), including the backslash.

`'\\['` is a JavaScript string literal that contains a backslash (`\\`) and an open square bracket (`[`). In the compiled program the string is `\[`.

`'\\\['` is a JavaScript string literal that contains a correctly encoded backslash (`\\`) followed by the combination of characters `\[` that looks like an escape sequence but doesn't mean anything. Because this combination is not defined and `\` by itself does not mean anything, the JavaScript interpreter ignores the backslash and corrects the string; it becomes identical to the first one (`\[`).

The behaviour is [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Escaping_characters):

> For characters not listed in the table, a preceding backslash is ignored, but this usage is deprecated and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is a special character. Literally, JS talk to browser to interpret the symbol after `\` **as is**. Sometimes it calls screening or shielding.
That is why we can write smth like that: `console.log("Double \"quotes\" inside another one.");` with the result of `Double "quotes" inside another one.` without any error. Although that is not the way we need to use anywhere.

1. `"\\\["` separates into 2 parts: `\\` and `\[`. First returns `\` and the second returns `[`. Finally it is `\[`.
2. `"\\["` separates into 2 parts: `\\` and `[`. First returns `\` and the second returns `[`. Finally it is `\[`.